# Put Multiple Columns data into Consecutive Columns

Tags: sql-server

I’m not sure how to even word/explain what I’m looking for. I have data like this:

| CODE_NBR | LIST1 | LIST2 | LIST3 | LIST4 | LIST5 | LIST6 | LIST7 | LIST8 | LIST9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | L19 | L14 | L15 | L16 |  | L18 |  | L54 |  |
| AB1 | L60 | L14 |  | L16 |  | L18 |  |  | L56 |

I want them to be put into consecutive columns like this, basically removing gaps between:

| CODE_NBR | NewList1 | NewList2 | NewList3 | NewList4 | NewList5 | NewList6 | NewList7 | NewList8 | NewList9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | L19 | L14 | L15 | L16 | L18 | L54 |  |  |  |
| AB1 | L60 | L14 | L16 | L18 | L56 |  |  |  |  |

I've tried unpivoting the columns into one column them pivoting them back and they just go back where they were. I also tried dynamic SQL and it still put them in the same place they were originally in, so I'm not sure how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do. This is sample data

```
--DROP TABLE PLANS;

CREATE TABLE PLANS
(
    CODE_NBR nvarchar(3),
    ListTable1 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable2 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable3 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable4 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable5 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable6 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable7 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable8 nvarchar(10), 
    ListTable9 nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO PLANS 
VALUES ('AA1','L19','L14','L15','L16','','L18','','L54',''),  
       ('AB1','L60','L14','','L16','','L18','','','L56'),
       ('AC1','','','','','','','','','L56');

WITH UNPVT AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             A.CODE_NBR,
             ListTable1 L1,
             ListTable2 L2,
             ListTable3 L3,
             ListTable4 L4,
             ListTable5 L5,
             ListTable6 L6,
             ListTable7 L7,
             ListTable8 L8,
             ListTable9 L9
         FROM 
             PLANS A) TMP
UNPIVOT
    (LISTS FOR 
          LISTALL IN (L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9)
    ) UNPIV),
LISTCOUNT AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CODE_NBR, COUNT(LISTS) LCOUNT, 
        MIN(lists) firstlist, max(lists) lastlist
    FROM 
        UNPVT 
    GROUP BY 
        CODE_NBR
),
PVT AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (SELECT * FROM UNPVT) T1
    PIVOT 
        (MAX(LISTS)
            FOR LISTALL IN (L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9)) T1
)
SELECT * 
FROM PVT
```

Comment: Please show the tries, so anyone with some free time can debug those for your... 

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Why do you have *nine* List columns? Why not a single list column with (up to?) 9 rows per `CODE_NBR`?

Comment: Sorry first time posting here. I'm trying to figure out how to add a code sample

Comment: just use [edit], and change the code I added... 

Comment: There are 9 list columns because there can be that many different lists. I didn't design it, I'm just trying to re-write someone's access database in SQL server for a new powerapp

Comment: just to be clear, are you trying to get a query in which the result would only get fields with values inside?

Comment: yes, but listed in columns consecutively, not in the column they originally came from

Comment: If those are "lists', what you ask will break them and move the data from one list to another. Data is *never* added "horizontally" in a table. Even in an Excel spreadsheet what you ask would create serious problems

Comment: Why are you asking for this? What real problem are you trying to solve by changing the fields of the values? A row isn't a list, it represents a **R**elation between its values. That's why tables and queries have fixed and always know fields. You can't just move a `Day-Of-Death` left into a `Day-of-Birth` field, or a `EndsAt` into a `StartsAt`

Comment: When doing `SELECT * FROM UNPVT`  you will see empty values in the column `LISTS`  (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/WXelHkBa))   I do think you have to filer those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery.

`CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing each row as XML. Amazingly enough that XML is omitting columns with NULL values. By doing that we are shifting real data to the left.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    CODE_NBR VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
    LIST1 CHAR(3),
    LIST2 CHAR(3),
    LIST3 CHAR(3),
    LIST4 CHAR(3),
    LIST5 CHAR(3),
    LIST6 CHAR(3),
    LIST7 CHAR(3),
    LIST8 CHAR(3),
    LIST9 CHAR(3)
);
INSERT @tbl (CODE_NBR, LIST1, LIST2, LIST3, LIST4, LIST5, LIST6, LIST7, LIST8, LIST9) VALUES
('AA1', 'L19', 'L14', 'L15', 'L16', NULL, 'L18', NULL, 'L54', NULL),    
('AB1', 'L60', 'L14', NULL, 'L16', NULL, 'L18', NULL, NULL, 'L56');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- after
SELECT CODE_NBR
    , x.value('(/root/*[2]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST1
    , x.value('(/root/*[3]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST2
    , x.value('(/root/*[4]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST3
    , x.value('(/root/*[5]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST4
    , x.value('(/root/*[6]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST5
    , x.value('(/root/*[7]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST6
    , x.value('(/root/*[8]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST7
    , x.value('(/root/*[9]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST8
    , x.value('(/root/*[10]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS NewLIST9
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x);
```

**Output**

| CODE_NBR | LIST1 | LIST2 | LIST3 | LIST4 | LIST5 | LIST6 | LIST7 | LIST8 | LIST9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | L19 | L14 | L15 | L16 | NULL | L18 | NULL | L54 | NULL |
| AB1 | L60 | L14 | NULL | L16 | NULL | L18 | NULL | NULL | L56 |

| CODE_NBR | NewLIST1 | NewLIST2 | NewLIST3 | NewLIST4 | NewLIST5 | NewLIST6 | NewLIST7 | NewLIST8 | NewLIST9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | L19 | L14 | L15 | L16 | L18 | L54 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| AB1 | L60 | L14 | L16 | L18 | L56 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Comment: Note that JSON has the same "null skipping" behavior, you may try it to compare performance if your dataset is big enough to see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to your pivot approach:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Code_NBR VARCHAR(3), List1 VARCHAR(3), List2 VARCHAR(3), List3 VARCHAR(3), List4 VARCHAR(3), List5 VARCHAR(3), List6 VARCHAR(3), List7 VARCHAR(3), List8 VARCHAR(3), List9 VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @Table (Code_NBR, List1, List2, List3, List4, List5, List6, List7, List8, List9) VALUES
('AA1', 'L19', 'L14', 'L15', 'L16', NULL, 'L18', NULL, 'L54',   NULL),
('AB1', 'L60', 'L14', NULL,  'L16', NULL, 'L18', NULL, NULL,    'L56');

SELECT Code_NBR, MAX(List1) AS List1, MAX(List2) AS List2, MAX(List3) AS List3, MAX(List4) AS List4, MAX(List5) AS List5, MAX(List6) AS List6, MAX(List7) AS List7, MAX(List8) AS List8, MAX(List9) AS List9
  FROM (
        SELECT *, 'List' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code_NBR ORDER BY List) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS NewList
          FROM @Table
            UNPIVOT (
                     x FOR List IN (List1, List2, List3, List4, List5, List6, List7, List8, List9)
                    ) p 
       ) a
    PIVOT (
           MAX(x) FOR NewList IN (List1, List2, List3, List4, List5, List6, List7, List8, List9)
          ) p2
 GROUP BY Code_nbr;
```

After an `UNPIVOT`, Using `ROW_NUMBER` you can reassign the column names and then `PIVOT` them back.

| Code_NBR | List1 | List2 | List3 | List4 | List5 | List6 | List7 | List8 | List9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | L19 | L14 | L15 | L16 | L18 | L54 |  |  |  |
| AB1 | L60 | L14 | L16 | L18 | L56 |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
   SELECT CODE_NBR, value, ordinal, row_number() over (partition by CODE_NBR order by ordinal) R
   FROM mytable m
   CROSS APPLY string_split(m.LIST1+','+m.LIST2+','+m.LIST3+','+m.LIST4+','+
        m.LIST5+','+m.LIST6+','+m.LIST7+','+m.LIST8+','+m.LIST9,',',1) x
   WHERE value<>'' 
)
 UPDATE mytable
 SET LIST1 = value1.value,
     LIST2 = value2.value,
     LIST3 = value3.value,
     LIST4 = value4.value,
     LIST5 = value5.value,
     LIST6 = value6.value,
     LIST7 = value7.value,
     LIST8 = value8.value,
     LIST9 = value9.value
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN cte as value1 ON value1.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value1.R=1
LEFT JOIN cte as value2 ON value2.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value2.R=2
LEFT JOIN cte as value3 ON value3.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value3.R=3
LEFT JOIN cte as value4 ON value4.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value4.R=4
LEFT JOIN cte as value5 ON value5.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value5.R=5
LEFT JOIN cte as value6 ON value6.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value6.R=6
LEFT JOIN cte as value7 ON value7.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value7.R=7
LEFT JOIN cte as value8 ON value8.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value8.R=8
LEFT JOIN cte as value9 ON value9.CODE_NBR=mytable.CODE_NBR and value9.R=9
;


SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

First put the values in a  list, and then split them....

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/dOsAuLHK)

P.S. The first *try* (in the dbfiddle) is a naive approach, which should be ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I have made the solution dynamic. I tried to get the all the columns where you want to do the analysis and used pivot to find out your desired answer.

```
declare @col1 varchar(MAX);
select @col1 = concat('concat_ws(' , ''',''' , ','
,string_agg(column_name, ','),')') from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'PLANS' and 
column_name <> 'CODE_NBR';

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select code_nbr, ' +(@col1) +' as [col] into [agg1] from plans';
exec(@sql);

select * from
(
    select 
        a.code_nbr , 
        value as code_value , 
        concat('NewList' ,row_number() over(partition by code_nbr order by code_nbr)) as column_name 
    from agg1 as a cross apply string_split(col, ',') where 
    value <> ''
) as a
Pivot
(
    max(code_value) for column_name
    in (NewList1 , NewList2 , NewList3 , NewList4 , NewList5 , NewList6 ,   NewList7 , NewList8 , NewList9)
) as pivot_tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

A manual unpivot-repivot without joins, xml/json, dynamic sql or special pivoting operators:

```
with upvt as (
    select CODE_NBR, idx, val,
         row_number() over (partition by CODE_NBR
                            order by case when val <> '' then 1 else 2 end, idx) as rn
    from PLANS cross apply (values
        (1, LIST1), (2, LIST2), (3, LIST3), (4, LIST4), (5, LIST5),
        (6, LIST6), (7, LIST7), (8, LIST8), (9, LIST9)) as u(idx, val)
)
select CODE_NBR,
    min(case rn when 1 then val end) as LIST1,
    min(case rn when 2 then val end) as LIST2,
    min(case rn when 3 then val end) as LIST3,
    min(case rn when 4 then val end) as LIST4,
    min(case rn when 5 then val end) as LIST5,
    min(case rn when 6 then val end) as LIST6,
    min(case rn when 7 then val end) as LIST7,
    min(case rn when 8 then val end) as LIST8,
    min(case rn when 9 then val end) as LIST9
from upvt
group by CODE_NBR;
```